# How to get back to Wild woods in God of War-2018?

Tags: god-of-war-2018

I've been playing God of War-2018 for a couple of hours and noticed that I didn't get some items on the first level on the map (Wild woods) now I'm on River Pass, but I'm lost and couldn't find a way to go back to the previous level.

Answer (score 12):

I found the answer here on [PlayStation trophies](https://www.playstationtrophies.org/forum/god-of-war-2018-/325649-how-get-back-wild-woods.html#post6210620).
It says that you'll have the fast travelling option after some time in the game. So just keep playing the game and you'll unlock it, then you can come back and collect the stuff you left behind.